# Test if velocity variable equal to digit

Tags: java, themes, liferay, velocity

I am working with velocity and I need to compare a variable to 1. Below is my snippet:

```
#set ($expand = "")
#set ($counter = 1)
#if ($counter == 1)
    #set ($expand = "naresh")
#end
```

Here I am printing `expand` value:

```
$expand
```

It always gives me an empty string, not the string I set in the condition true block.
I think I might be wrong with the comparing value.
Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: It works on my machine. How do you use $expand?

Answer (score 1):

Advising to keep it simple and pass already predefined or `null` values into `velocity` templates. So basically you could easily test this in `Java` and in `velocity` template just do simple check like this:

```
#if (!$variable)
  <div>do something here if the variable is null</div>
#end
```

More documentation could be found in [Velocity Wiki CheckingForNull](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/CheckingForNull) and [Velocity User Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#References).